# Get Access token in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, google-oauth

I am working under login to Google via OAuth2 spring-security
I was successfully login via oauth2 and received Principal, but in my project requirements, I need also set to user principal access token, how can I do this?

Thank you, for you help

Answer (score 0):

If you can explain your scenario more, I can help better. But generally in Spring Security you have to specify the Authorities for each of your system roles to have that user access the specified level.

[image]